# AutoMapper cannot mapping Reference or using UseDestinationValue

Tags: c#, automapper

**Code First**

```cs
class Woman
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Family
{
    public string SweetName { get; set; }
    public Woman Wife { get; set; }
}
class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Woman, Woman>();
        CreateMap<Family, Family>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Wife, o => o.UseDestinationValue());
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void main()
    {
        // Initialize
        var ce = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
        ce.AddProfile(new MyProfile());
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(ce).CreateMapper();

        var oldWoman = new Woman { Name = "Alice" };
        var newWoman = mapper.Map<Woman>(oldWoman);
        Console.WriteLine($"oldWoman.Equals(newWoman) : {oldWoman.Equals(newWoman)}");
        // false 

        var oldFamily = new Family { SweetName = "family one", Wife = oldWoman };
        var newFamily = mapper.Map<Family>(oldFamily);
        Console.WriteLine($"oldFamily.Equals(newFamily) : {oldFamily.Equals(newFamily)}"); 
        // false

        Console.WriteLine($"oldFamily.Wife.Equals(newFamily.Wife) : {oldFamily.Wife.Equals(newFamily.Wife)}"); 
        // false
        // here i wanna reference of oldfamily.wife pass to newfamily.wife's
    }
}
```

I have set UseDestinationValue(), it doesn't work?

if I don't create woman map, the two wife's reference is equal.

like this:

```
class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        //CreateMap<Woman, Woman>();
        CreateMap<Family, Family>();
        //.ForMember(d => d.Wife, o => o.UseDestinationValue());
    }
}
```

PS. no creating woman map and UseDestinationValue is unnecessary. two wife's reference is equal without creating woman map and using UseDestinationValue method.

**How to pass the reference in this case with using create a map of woman class?**

***Updated 1***

A strange way to solve this :

```
class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Woman, Woman>();
        CreateMap<Family, Family>()
            .AfterMap((s, d) => d.Wife = s.Wife);
    }
}
```

it works, but it's not the ultimate way obviously.

it has been mapped. XD

do expect mapping after doing unexpected mapping?

Comment: Why are you creating a mapping for the same class? Do you want to perform a deep clone?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto im not createing a mapping for the same class. Actually i want to perform a shallow clone.

Comment: @ByByeBye Does it work when you use `ResolveUsing()`?

Comment: @Progman nope, it seems depends on wherther using CreateMap<Woman, Woman>(); or not.

Comment: @ByByeBye You can use an `Ignore()` call to prevent the mapping of the `Family.Wife` property and then use `AfterMap()` to "fix" the mapping by using the original object instance. This way it doesn't get mapped by AutoMapper.

Comment: @Progman 3Q, it can be a temp way to solve.